# What is the value for spacing between lines in a wrapped CATextLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, catextlayer

I am trying to create a CATextLayer with a frame that is the exact size of 3 lines of text + the spacing in between this text. I know that my font size is 12.

The height of the frame should therefore be 12*3 + 2*spaceSize.

I want the number that spaceSize is equal to, I can't find it anywhere.

---

The font I'm using is Helvetica if that helps.

Comment: Why not use the API to calculate the frame required to fit the text for a given font? `NSAttributedText boundingRect` will give you the size. Be sure to include the proper attributes such as font and paragraph style (if not default).

Comment: @rmaddy I want to set a max width, and some other things. This is a toy example.

Comment: Your comment doesn't change mine.

Answer (score 4):

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString( (CFMutableAttributedStringRef) textLayer.string);
CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
CFRelease(framesetter);
CGFloat layerHeight = ceil(suggestedSize.height);
spaceSize = (layerHeight - 36) / 2.0;
```